# Merge dataframes based on 3 different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes based on 3 columns. Three columns are id, email, mobile number. The problem is that sometimes only id matches, sometimes only email and others only mobile number. So what I want to do is to check for ever column at once and added it to my final table.

I tried df1.merge(df2,how=,'left', on=[id, name, mobile number]) but in this case it only returns rows with the three columns matching.

Comment: This is the indented behavior. You can write other joins like df1.merge(df2,how=,'left', on=[id])  and the use pd.concat() to join the results.  A join only works if all fields that included are the same on both tables, for anything "fuzzy" you need to write custom code.  Same tools/libraries have specific shortcuts for that.

Comment: To complement to comment above, you could think of merging both dataframes three times (each time on only one of your keys), and union them in a way. From my point of view, this depends on the logic behind your data and the specific use case you want to implement (dropping duplicates based on some condition, ...)